# How to create a commit without using personal acccess token?

Tags: github-actions

I am using github action to release a tag with commit update version without using PAT(personal acccess token) as below

```
    - name: Create a tag with new version
        uses: actions/github-script@v3
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            github.git.createRef({
              owner: owner,
              repo: repo,
              ref: "refs/tags/${{ env.NEW_VERSION }}",
              sha: sha
            })
```

I can create a tag normally with this code without any commit.
But I want to commit some changes and push in this tag.
When I add commit command to the workflow:

```
git commit -a -m "Update new version ${NEW_VERSION }"
```

the error "Author identity unknown" will be thrown. I know this issue occured because I did not add name and email or use PAT in the workflow.
I want to make a commit before creating a tag and push it by using github_token only. Anyone can help me with this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: have you tried running `git config user.email my@email.com` before the commit?

Comment: @rethab I can make the commit by add user name and email before as you advice, but I do not want to use it because it may be violated

Comment: what do you mean with violated?

Comment: it means in my side, there is a require I should not using user name and email in the source code.

Comment: You can use dummy@company.com as email address. It doesn't matter what you set there, you just need _something_

Answer (score -1):

You can just do:

```yaml
- name: Tag Release
  run: |
    git tag -d v${{ steps.git_version.outputs.version }} 2> /dev/null || echo 'local ref does not exist'
    git push origin :v${{ steps.git_version.outputs.version }} 2> /dev/null || echo 'remote ref does not exist'
    git tag v${{ steps.git_version.outputs.version }}
    git push origin v${{ steps.git_version.outputs.version }}
```